# Soap Body contains only partial contents of file

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-micro-integrator, apache-commons-vfs, axiom

I have a VFS proxy in wso2 which is monitoring a folder.
I have set the transport.vfs.Streaming to True
`<parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>`
But when I try to get the file contents I do not get the entire file content in my mediation flow

`messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getText();`

This only returns half content of my file.

I tried setting the transport.vfs.Streaming to false
still the same result